# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:ACKNOWLEDGED

Tags: mongodb, maven, groovy, soapui

[SOAP UI error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAlfl.png) I have encountered the above error message while executing in SOAPUI tool, as the same code works properly while executing through Maven.

I have a search on google about this problem and found that this issue occurred due to the conflict in Jar file. I have removed the Mongo DB jar which is causing the conflict. 
Dependency in POM file is

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my bin/ext folder, I have added
bson-3.4.2.jar and
mongo-java-driver-3.10.2

My code is,

```
import com.mongodb.*
import com.mongodb.client.*
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection
import org.bson.*
try{
    def mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(mongoURI);
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("DatabaseName");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
    database.getCollection("CollectionName");
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    log.info "Documents is- "+cursor.next().toJson();
    }
    }finally {
    cursor.close();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
    log.info "test Exception is "+e.getMessage();
    }
    finally{
    log.info "Finally block";
    }
```

Comment: I don't see ACKNOWLEDGED in your code.

Comment: Yes, ACKNOWLEDGED is not in code. But still,  I am getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:ACKNOWLEDGED error

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace. Otherwise no way to help.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for your reply. Please find above error log file for full stacktrace.

Comment: google search for `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:ACKNOWLEDGED` gives result that you have mixed mongo client version libraries in your classpath...

Comment: @daggett thank you very much, really appreciate your help. I have resolved the problem by deleting old mongo client version libraries from C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\lib folder.